# Google Apps Script not recognizing strings with parentheses and brackets as part of the string

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I have a conditional that is supposed to compare two strings:

```
if (parametros.toString().toLowerCase().match(valor_celda_activa.toString().toLowerCase()) != null){
...actions here...
}
```

This works ok UNTIL there is some parentheses or bracket inside the string.

> **Working example strings:**
> parametros = "1.01 - Sourcing Gathering information"
> valor_celda_activa = "1.01 - Sourcing Gathering information"

> **NOT working example strings:**
> parametros = "1.01 - [Sourcing] Gathering information"
> valor_celda_activa = "1.01 - [Sourcing] Gathering information"

Note the brackets inside the strings. As long as the brackets are present, the code won't work. This also happens with parentheses.

Haven't actually found this kind of specific situation from someone else on the internet.

This is really my first question on StackOverFlow so feel free to feedback or request more information that I might have missed.

Comment: I modified you tags to improve your chances of getting a good response.  There's a couple of regex gurus around here that can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[String.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) expects a regular expression. Square brackets `[]` have special meaning in [regex](/questions/tagged/regex).  For plain text matching, just use `===`:

```
if (parametros.toString().toLowerCase() === valor_celda_activa.toString().toLowerCase()){
```